# check if arrays match regardless of order in postgres, SQLAlchemy, python

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have this relationship in postgres:

`ChatRoom` -> One-To-Many -> `ChatRoomUserMetadata`

`ChatRoom` has the primary key `chat_room_id`.
`ChatRoomUserMetadata` contains the field `user_id` which is a `UUID` in postgres.

In a python function, I have an array: `user_ids`, and I want to fetch the `ChatRoom` which has exactly those `user_ids` in its related `ChatRoomUserMetadata` rows.

For example if I have `ChatRoom` **A** with `ChatRoomUserMetadata` **B, C, D**, and I also have `ChatRoom` **E** with `ChatRoomUserMetadata` **C, D** and then I have `user_ids` array `["D", "C"]`, I need some kind of query on `ChatRoom` to return `ChatRoom` E.

In SQL, I managed to get the following query which I *believe* works:

`user_ids = ["00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"]`

```
SELECT chat_room.chat_room_id
FROM chat_room
JOIN chat_room_user_metadata
ON chat_room.chat_room_id = chat_room_user_metadata.chat_room_id
WHERE user_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
OR user_id = '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'
GROUP BY chat_room.chat_room_id
HAVING (
    ARRAY['00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid,'11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'::uuid] @> array_agg(chat_room_user_metadata.user_id) AND
    ARRAY['00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid,'11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'::uuid] <@ array_agg(chat_room_user_metadata.user_id)
);
```

Translating to SQLAlchemy, I got the following:

```
import from sqlalchemy import func, and_

chat_room = (
        db_session.query(ChatRoom)
        .join(
            ChatRoomUserMetadata,
            and_(
                ChatRoom.chat_room_id == ChatRoomUserMetadata.chat_room_id,

                # Just used to filter out ChatRoomUserMetadata which has a user not even in our array. for performance
                ChatRoomUserMetadata.user_id.in_(user_ids),
            ),
        )
        .group_by(ChatRoom.chat_room_id)
        .having(
            and_(
                func.array_agg(ChatRoomUserMetadata.user_id).op("<@")(user_ids),
                func.array_agg(ChatRoomUserMetadata.user_id).op("@>")(user_ids),
            )
        ).first()
    )
```

This doesn't throw any errors, but it doesn't work properly. It appears to return more of a "contains" result. For example, if:

`user_ids = ['00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000']`

the query will return a `ChatRoom` that has:

`user_ids = ['00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111']`.

I need to basically match arrays regardless of their order, and the elements must ***exactly match***.

Lots of searching yielded no results. Any help is appreciated. Lmk if more context is needed.